# Why is "aClass.aProperty" not callable?

Tags: python

```
class A:
  @property
  def p(self): return 2

  def q(self): return 2

a = A()
A.p(a) #>> TypeError: 'property' object is not callable

A.q(a) #>> no error, returns 2
```

Why is this? I understand if I referred to the property on an *instance* : a.p would simply return the method return value, but I am trying to start with the property on the class. I would have expected no error above, with both evaluating to 2.

Comment: Note that declaring your functions on one line, no matter how small, is rather bad form as it hurts readability.

Comment: So I am starting to see some of the mechanics of how @property behaves. I am not clear about the reasons. Specifically:

Answer (score 20):

You're digging into the world of [`descriptors`](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).  `A.p` is a `property` and properties are *descriptors*.  It's a class that has magic methods (`__get__`, `__set__` ...) which get called when the descriptor is accessed on an *instance*.  The particular method accessed depends on how it's accessed of course.  Accessing a descriptor on a *class* simply returns the descriptor itself and no magic is performed -- In this case, the `property` descriptor isn't callable so you get an error.

Notice what happens if you call `__get__`:

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def p(self):  
        return 2

a = A()
print (A.p.__get__(a)) #2
```

`foo = A.p.__get__(a)` is what actually happens under the hood when you do `foo = a.p`.  I think that's pretty spiffy...

Answer (score 8):

Because properties aren't callable:

```
In [3]: class A(object):
   ...:   @property
   ...:   def p(self): return 2
   ...:

In [4]: A.p
Out[4]: <property at 0x2d919a8>

In [5]: dir(A.p)
Out[5]:
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__delete__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__get__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__set__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'deleter',
 'fdel',
 'fget',
 'fset',
 'getter',
 'setter']
```

Note the lack of a `__call__` method. This is because properties can wrap up more than one function.

Here's what happens if you try to invoke the property as a method on an instance:

```
In [6]: a = A()

In [7]: a.p()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Marcin\<ipython-input-7-16c8de382321> in <module>()
----> 1 a.p()

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct, but I think it's a little difficult to understand why `A.p` gives you a property while `a.p` calls a method unless you have a basic understanding of descriptors.

Comment: @mgilson This question is not about what happens with `a.p`. It is about what happens with `A.p()` vs `a.p()`, which in both cases would be an error.

Answer (score 2):

The property decorator turns your method into a property, it is no longer a function object,  but  a `property` instead, and is therefore not callable

Comment: It's not that a class doesn't "see" the object as a function. It's not a function object.

Comment: how to call it then?